Usb memory read in a linux computer, but not in another linux computer
both computers are running debian, computer A uses debian bookworm and computer B uses debain bullseye.
I tried with lsusb in computer A and it's recognized, same brand usb sticks in A computer can't be unmount. A and B use Mate desktop.
In computer B they can be used, no error shown in B computer.
I try to unmount-extract from A and says for hours (or forever, never tried to wait more than 2 hours) that is writing data on it. If I take out the usb memory from the usb slot in computer A, can't be read anymore in that computer, can't be read neither in B, but can be formated, in computer A can't be formated.
After formating the usb in B computer, computer A doesn't read them anymore but computer B does.
No idea what else to try

gnome-disks shows that is reading the drive, other usb drives work without problem

I had the same problem with a laptop.
I couldn't unmount the stick and when I tried to copy data, for example with dd, dd stopped the process at 30 percent and showed a corrupt file system only on this laptop.
Simply i removed the USB stick and plugged it in again but I had to restart the computer so that it would recognize it again.
After I tried a different USB port everything worked normally on the laptop, so the USB port was the problem, I later found out that there was a problem with the voltage
If that didn't work on both computers, I would have said the USB stick was broken but since it works in B but not in A, I would say that the USB port is broken or has a problem or on A you have some problem with software or driver for the usb port.
I would try a different USB port on the computer and see if the problem still exists and if possible, try another USB stick.
Otherwise you have to check whether it is a driver/software problem or, like mine, a voltage problem
p.s. Maybe you can start a live system on computer A and see if the stick works
